# Nontrivial norm values in rings of integers

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $L=Q(\sqrt{d})$ for some square-free integer $d\not\equiv_4 1$. In this case the ring of integers of $L$ is $O_L=\{x+\sqrt{d}y \mid x,y\in Z\}$ so the norms of $O_L$ are exactly  $x^2-dy^2$ for $x,y$ integers. Clearly, all the squares of integers are norms, and I would like to find what is the smallest norm (in absolute value) which is not a square, compared to the discriminant of the field.

If $d<0$, then the first such norm is $d=\frac{D}{4}$ where $D$ is the discriminant. If $d>0$, then from the inequality $(\lfloor{\sqrt{d}}\rfloor)^2<d<(\lfloor{\sqrt{d}}\rfloor+1)^2$ we get that $N(\lfloor{\sqrt{d}}\rfloor+\sqrt{d})\leq 2\sqrt{d}$. The problem is that this norm can still be a square.

Let $$m_L=\min\big\{|N(x)|\mid x\in O_L, \;N(x)\notin\mathbb{Z}^{(2)}\big\}$$
where $|N(x)|$ is the absolute value of the norm of $x$.
I would like to know if $m_L$ can be bounded by some function of the discriminant of $L$ (for $d>0$) which is better than $O(D)$.
Similarly, I would like to know the same for
$$m'_L=\min \big\{|N(x)|\mid x\in (O_L - \mathbb{Z}\cdot O_L^\times), \;N(x)\notin\mathbb{Z}^{(2)}\big\},$$
i.e. we allow squares of integers which do not come from norms of integers multiplied by some invertible element.

Secondly, I would be happy to know if there are some nice conditions on field extensions of higher degrees such that there is a good bound on the smallest non trivial norm (maybe for cyclic extensions?).

Comment: Perhaps something can be gleaned from the continued fraction expansion of $\sqrt d$, as the values of $x^2-dy^2$ not exceeding $2\sqrt d$ in absolute value can all be found from this continued fraction.

Comment: See http://arxiv.org/abs/1310.6608 and http://arxiv.org/abs/1202.6022

Comment: @FranzLemmermeyer : Thanks. These references are very helpful, in particular the one on the simplest cubic fields. Do you happen to know similar results for other families of cubic extensions?

Comment: You should be able to do something similar in all families of fields where you can parametrize the full unit group. In particular there should be many examples in complex cubic fields.

Comment: Your notation for $m_L$ and $m_L'$ didn't match what you were asking. Especially, they specified that the norms not be in $\mathbb{Z}$, which is never the case here. I've edited the notation to match the question. (Often people use $S^{(2)}$ to mean squares of elements in $S$.)

Comment: Provided I have properly interpreted what you meant to ask, I think the links from @FranzLemmermeyer answer your question.